# Is there a function in mongoose where I can check if a certain id exists in one collection and insert in other collection if it does?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 2 models - Driver and User. Both of them rate each other, so while creating the API, how can I check whether a certain userId exists in db, and if it exists, I want to add to my driver's rating array such that a new object is added like this.

```
{userId:xyz/*Already Checked in the Db that it exists*/,rating:4}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use two requests.

```
const user = await Users.findOne({_id: userId});

if (user){
  const driver = await Drivers.findOne({_id: driverId});
  driver.ratings.push({userId, rating: 4})
  await driver.save();
}
```